# How to create two Update actions in one Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

So, naturally, whenever one specifies a resource inside of the **routes.rb** file like...

`resources :users`

... this resource generates 7 sample actions...

```
users#new     (GET)
users#create  (POST)
users#show    (GET)
users#edit    (GET)
users#update  (PATCH/PUT)
users#destroy (DELETE)
```

### **Problem:**

Now, what I want to achieve and cannot do is to add an additional update action to my controller file so that it would be able to update **different params**. Different to the first update action that is.

Inside of my **users_controller.rb** file I have...

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  .
  .
  .
  # First update action
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  # Second update action
  def update_number_two
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_other_params)
      flash[:success] = "Other params updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'other_view' 
    end
  end

  private

    # Params for the first action
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Params for the second action
    def user_other_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:other_param)
    end
end
```

So the problem that I have is, in order to make the code above work I need to add a custom update action route to my routes.rb file.

I have tried adding this to my routes...

```
patch 'users#update_number_two'
put   'users#update_number_two'
```

... and some other things, but none worked.

If someone could tell me what I should add to my routes.rb file or just nudge me in the right direction, your help is appreciated.

Comment: When do you want it to go to `update` and when to `update_number_two`?

Comment: Consider them being two separate update actions, one that executes inside of one view, and another that executes inside of the other. Basically, depends which view the user is on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to add another action to a specific resource you need to use `member`:

> **2.10 Adding More RESTful Actions**
>
> You are not limited to the seven routes that RESTful routing creates by default. If you like, you may add additional routes that apply to the collection or individual members of the collection.

```
resources :users do
  member do
    patch :update_number_two
    put :update_number_two
  end
end
```

then, when you want to update choose different `action` of the form(`update_number_two_user_path` || `/users/:id/update_number_two`)

```
update_number_two_user PATCH  /users/:id/update_number_two(.:format) users#update_number_two
                       PUT    /users/:id/update_number_two(.:format) users#update_number_two
```

run `rake:routes` to see the results

more information: [Adding More RESTful Actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: Amazing!! Thanks, it works! Saved me a day worth of headache.